# Morris graph design

Tags: javascript, graph, morris.js

I recently bought the template [image: Centaurus], And I wanted to use the graph design that is part of the template, but when I use Morris with Javascript it ruins the colors of the graph.

Code:
JS:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    // Fuel per 100k data //
    var fuel_data = <?php echo $fuelData; ?>;
    Morris.Line({
      element: 'graph-line',
      hideHover: 'auto',
      data: fuel_data,
      xkey: 'date',
      xLabels: 'Date',
      ykeys: ['views'],
      labels: ['Views'],
      resize: true,
      lineColors: ['white'],
      pointFillColors: ['white'],
      
    });
   
  });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="graph" id="graph-line" style="max-height: 335px; position: relative; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
                        </div>
```

The wanted layout:
[image: The wanted layout]

The current layout:
[image: The current layout]

As you can see, I managed to change the line and dots colors but coudn't change the label and the backlines ones.